# CakePHP White Screen of Death after Auth

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0

I seem to be having a very similar problem to many others but I can find no good solution.

After the user logs into the application, he is automatically redirect to the index() function of another controller. Despite being successfully redirected (according to the address bar) and having the debug levels set on high, all I get is a white screen.

Further complicating the problem, I have already logged in with other users (who are redirected to different functions of different controllers) and those have worked fine. Even when I clear the cache and make my index() function only echo "Hello World!", I get a white screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Turns out whitespace at the end of the file (after the ?> tag) was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out whitespace at the end of the file (after the ?> tag) was the problem.